# Multiple 'endings' to a function - return an object, return a string, raise an exception?

Tags: python

This one's a structure design problem, I guess. Back for some advice.

To start: I'm writing a module. Hence the effort of making it as usable to potential developers as possible.

Inside an object (let's call it `Swoosh`) I have a method which, when called, may result in either success (a new object is returned -- for insight: it's an `httplib.HTTPResponse`) or failure (surprising, isn't it?).

I'm having trouble deciding how to handle failures. There are two main cases here:

1. user supplied data that was incorrect
2. data was okay, but user interaction will be needed () - I need to pass back to the user a string that he or she will need to use in some way.

In (1) I decided to `raise ValueError()` with an appropriate description.
In (2), as I need to actually pass a `str` back to the user.. I'm not sure about whether it would be best to just `return` a string and leave it to the user to check what the function returned (`httplib.HTTPResponse` or `str`) or `raise` a custom exception? Is passing data through raising exceptions a good idea? I don't think I've seen this done anywhere, but on the other hand - I haven't seen much.

What would you, as a developer, expect from an object/function like this?

Or perhaps you find the whole design ridiculous - let me know, I'll happily learn.

Comment: I think it is perfectly okay to raise an Exception in both cases (with different types, of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As much as I like the approach of handling both cases with specifically-typed exceptions, I'm going to offer a different approach in case it helps: callbacks.

Callbacks tend to work better if you're already using an asynchronous framework like Twisted, but that's not their only place. So you might have a method that takes a function for each outcome, like this:

```
def do_request(on_success, on_interaction_needed, on_failure):
    """
    Submits the swoosh request, and awaits a response.

    If no user interaction is needed, calls on_success with a
    httplib.HTTPResponse object.

    If user interaction is needed, on_interaction_needed is
    called with a single string parameter.

    If the request failed, a ValueError is passed to on_failure
    """
    response = sumbit_request()
    if response.is_fine():
        on_success(response)
    elif response.is_partial()
        on_interaction_needed(response.message)
    else:
        on_failure(ValueError(response.message))
```

Being Python, there are a million ways to do this. You might not like passing an exception to a function, so you maybe just take a callback for the user input scenario. Also, you might pass the callbacks in to the `Swoosh` initialiser instead.

But there are drawbacks to this too, such as:

- Carelessness may result in spaghetti code
- You're allowing your caller to inject logic into your function (eg. exceptions raised in the callback will propagate out of `Swoosh`)
- My example here is simple, your actual function might not be

As usual, careful consideration and good documentation should avoid these problems. In theory.

Comment: This is a great suggestion and a tempting solution. I'll definitely need to consider this. I may actually try and use both (exception- and callback-based) solutions (as separate functions/objects) and do some quick usability analysis to find the one that proves more useful in most use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think raising an exception may actually be a pretty good idea in this case. Squashing multiple signals into a single return value of a function isn't ideal in Python, due to duck typing. It's not very Pythonic; every time you need to do something like:

```
result = some_function(...)
if isinstance(result, TypeA):
    do_something(result)
elif isinstance(result, TypeB):
    do_something_else(result)
```

you should be thinking about whether it's really the best design (as you're doing).

In this case, if you implement a custom exception, then the code that calls your function can just treat the returned value as a `HTTPResponse`. Any path where the function is unable to return something its caller can treat that way is handled by throwing an exception.

Likewise, the code that catches the exception and prompts the user with the message doesn't have to worry about the exact type of the thing its getting. It just knows that it's been explicitly instructed (by the exception) to show something to the user.

Answer (score 3):

If the user interaction case means the calling code has to show a prompt, get some input and them pass control back to your function, it might be ugly trying to handle that with an exception.  Eg,

```
try:
    Swoosh.method()
except UserInteraction, ex:
    # do some user interaction stuff
    # pass it back to Swoosh.method()?
    # did Swoosh need to save some state from the last call?
except ValueError:
    pass # whatever
```

If this user interaction is a normal part of the control flow, it might be cleaner to pass a user-interaction function into your method in the first place - then it can return a result to the Swoosh code.  For example:

```
# in Swoosh
def method(self, userinteractor):
    if more_info_needed:
        more_info = userinteractor.prompt("more info")
    ...

ui = MyUserInteractor(self) # or other state
Swoosh.method(ui)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a tuple of (httplib.HTTPResponse, str) with the str being optionally None.
Definitely raise an exception for 1).

If you don't like returning a tuple, you can also create a "response object" i.e. an instance of a new class ( lets say SomethingResponse ) that encapsulates the HTTPResponse with optional messages to the end-user( in the simplest case, just a str).